# awk complains about non-terminated string in command from concatenated strings

Tags: bash, awk

So the background is that I'm using date command inside awk. This command has differing flags on Linux/GNU from OSX. I'm storing correct command with flags in `$date` variable to work around this. The following awk command (that relies on string concatenation) fails:

```
awk '{
    cmd = "'$date'" substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""
    if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
        $1 = dd
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}'
```

with error:

```
awk: non-terminated string date... at source line 2
 context is
         >>>  <<<
awk: giving up
 source line number 3
```

When replacing awk with echo, the command outputs correctly:

```
{
    cmd = "date -r " substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""
    if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
        $1 = dd
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}
```

When the above script is put into awk directly, it also parses dates correctly (it takes first argument from each line of stdin as timestamp, strips microseconds and converts date to human-readable format).

`$date` variable is populated as follows:

```
date="date -d @"
date -d @1550000000 &>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    date="date -r "
fi
```

Comment: You should pass date variable to use using `-v name=value` syntax i.e. `awk -v dt="$date" '...' file`

Comment: would I just call it $dt within awk script after?

Comment: That worked, I can accept the answer if the comment is moved there. I'm still curious what the problem with string concatenation above is (even if it's not the best solution, I want to understand this bash quirk).

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov, the problem looks like the awk apostrophe is closed immediately after the first double quote.  The very last character, after the closing brace, appears to be the intended one.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov the specific problem you had is something to do with how you are populating the shell variable `date`. One reason to set/use an awk variable rather than letting a shell variable expand within your script is to avoid getting cryptic error messages like this when your shell variable contains something unexpected. We can't see how you're populating it so we can't help much with explaining the issue. Aside: don't create variables with the same name as the name of commands - that is a sure way to obfuscate your code and create insidious bugs!

Comment: @EdMorton I updated the question with the logic you requested, just in case someone can clarify it. As for your advice, I agree that generally it's a bad practice, however, for commands that are specifically meant to abstract OS-specific functionality of a command with that exact name I find that it makes the script more clear - it's a pattern I adopted a while ago.

Comment: You should try to shake that practice as it is a bad idea that will have you and anyone else trying to understand your code in future gnashing their teeth trying to understand/enhance/debug it. Name the variables `command_var` or `os_command` or something/anything else that includes the command name rather than just `command`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a **complete**, minimal script (a [mcve]) that produces the error message you're asking about plus a line or 2 of sample input so we can help you debug it. We need a complete script that we can just copy/paste and execute as-is against input you provide to see the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use `-v name=value` syntax to pass shell variables to awk.

So in your case:

```
dt="date -r"

awk -v dt="$dt" '{
   cmd = dt substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""
   if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
       $1 = dd
   }
   close(cmd)
   print
}'
```

[More on: How do I use shell variables in awk scripts?](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24)

Also note helpful comment by Ed below that awk index starts at `1` instead of `0` in other languages such as `C/C++`.

Comment: While true that doesn't explain why the OP got the error message he claims from the script he posted. The 2nd arg to substr() is an integer starting at 1 - anything else (e.g. 0) is an invalid value which awk treats as if it were 1.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the index starting at 1, fixed that as well.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov yes, everything in awk starts at 1 - field numbers, string char positions, and array indices.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer, which was helpful to me to unravel the mystery, is around adjusting invocation method of awk and sidestepping the shell scripting question of shelling out to awk in this fashion.

I think I solved your shell script syntax problem. The setup:

args.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# copypasta code that shoves $1, $2... into 0-indexed bash array and prints it out.
# store arguments in a special array
args=("$@")
# get number of elements
ELEMENTS=${#args[@]}

# echo each element in array
# for loop
for (( i=0;i<$ELEMENTS;i++)); do
    echo ARGS[${i}]: ${args[${i}]}
done
```

test.sh:

```
date="date -r "
./args.sh '{
    cmd = "'$date'" substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""
    if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
        $1 = dd
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}'
```

Execution:

```
❯ ./args.sh one two three                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ARGS[0]: one
ARGS[1]: two
ARGS[2]: three

❯ bash test.sh          
ARGS[0]: { cmd = "date
ARGS[1]: -r
ARGS[2]: " substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\"" if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) { $1 = dd } close(cmd) print }
```

Explanation: spaces within your naively expanded un-doublequoted shell variable cause the test using `echo` to not reveal the actual root problem of awk receiving 3 args instead of 1 arg as expected. The first arg being the malformed incomplete awk program.

Here is my fix: I added doublequotes. The shell command looks pretty gnarly now with a great deal of quoting involved.

```
❯ cat test.sh     
date="date -r "
./args.sh '{
    cmd = "'"$date"'" substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""
    if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) {
        $1 = dd
    }
    close(cmd)
    print
}'
❯ bash test.sh   
ARGS[0]: { cmd = "date -r " substr( $1, 1, length($1) - 3 ) " +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\"" if ( (cmd | getline dd) > 0 ) { $1 = dd } close(cmd) print }
```

I will not comment on awk usage because I don't know how to use awk.

This type of code will be rather brittle but hey at least we don't have large backslash stacks in it yet. Anyone written a quine lately?

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Seems obvious in hindsight.

Comment: I'm satisfied that the resolution to the problem is in good physical proximity to the error message. in a way. Also that Awk even reported giving up parsing what you gave it was another clear sign.